# minted: How to change the start number for numering lines?

Tags: minted, code

When you use `\begin{minted}[linenos]`, it numbers the lines starting at 1, ie:

```
1 console.log('something')
2 console.log('another thing)
...
```

What should I do to start the numbering on any number, say, 5?

```
5 console.log('something')
6 console.log('another thing)
...
```

Comment: Try with `\begin{minted}[linenos,firstnumber=5]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `firstnumber` option along with `linenos`, as specified in the minted manual, p. 13.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos,firstnumber=5]{python}
def f(x):
    return 2 * x
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```